# Custom Composer Autoloader

Tags: php, static, constructor, composer-php, autoloader

Is there anyway to use a custom autoloader with Composer?

I have some libraries with many hundreds of classes, they are laid out in the directory structure as per PSR-0.

However they also include a static contructor (similar to Java's static initializer).

My autoloader I was using before composer would:

```
if (method_exists($class, '__static')) {
    call_user_func(array($class, '__static'));
}
```

So is there anyway to extend Composers default autoloader to also do this?

Comment: While @Jon seems to be cooking up quite a complete answer here, I would still like to stress that having custom instantiation like that sounds a bit wrong. If you really want to keep it though, putting Class::__static(); in the class's file might be an easier way of achieving this without having to hack the autoloader. I think relying on custom autoloading is not a great idea for portability and sanity. New developers looking at the code wouldn't get what's going on.

Comment: @Seldaek I don't "want" to keep it. I just don't have the budget approval to spend days refactoring hundreds of classes.

Comment: fair enough. Want wasn't the proper term, but I still think my point stands if you *have* to keep it :)

Answer (score 5):

### Hacking Composer

You can hack Composer's autoloader to support this by modifying `ClassLoader.php` (found inside the vendor directory):

```
public function loadClass($class)
{
    if ($file = $this->findFile($class)) {
        include $file;

        // Added your custom code:
        if (method_exists($class, '__static')) {
            call_user_func(array($class, '__static'));
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

However, this file is updated every time you run `composer update` (the source is included inside `composer.phar`), so making the modification once is not any good; you need a way of making this modification "permanent".

There are two ways of doing that I can think of:

#### Modifying Composer itself

This solution involves modifying `composer.phar`, which means that:

- Once the modification is performed, the hack will be always in effect without any additional setup
- Running `composer self-update` will overwrite the modified Composer source with the latest official version, undoing the hack

I 've written a short PHP script that performs a targeted find/replace on the Composer sources; it will only modify the exact code it is targeted at, which means that you need to run it on an unmodified version of Composer each time (it will refuse to touch an already modified version):

```
<?php

if (!Phar::canWrite()) {
    die ('The config setting phar.readonly must be set to 0 in php.ini');
}

$phar = new Phar('composer.phar');
$fileName = 'src/Composer/Autoload/ClassLoader.php';

try {
    $source = file_get_contents($phar[$fileName]);
}
catch (BadMethodCallException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die;
}

$find = <<<'END_ORIGINAL'
    public function loadClass($class)
    {
        if ($file = $this->findFile($class)) {
            include $file;

            return true;
        }
    }
END_ORIGINAL;

$replaceWith = <<< 'END_REPLACEMENT'
    public function loadClass($class)
    {
        if ($file = $this->findFile($class)) {
            include $file;

            // Add your custom code here!
            return true;
        }
    }
END_REPLACEMENT;

$find = preg_replace('/\s+/', '\\s+', preg_quote($find));
$modified = preg_replace('/'.$find.'/', $replaceWith, $source);

if ($source == $modified) {
    echo 'Could not find replacement target, aborting';
    die;
}

file_put_contents($phar[$fileName], $modified);
echo 'Replacement done, file saved';
```

#### Using a post-update script

Composer allows you to attach [scripts](http://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md) to your root package; a post-update script that modifies `ClassLoader.php` is a good way to make the change stick across updates while leaving Composer's sources intact.

It's quite simple to adapt the code from the previous section to do this. Ideally the script would be a static PHP class method, but in order to do this you *must* create a new Composer package that autoloads using Composer's PSR-0 autoloader because the class has to be autoloaded and currently it is [not possible](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/1430) to autoload classes using classmap during Composer's update process.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I did notice that if I modified the autoloader it got blown away every time I updated. While your options seems feasible, I might instead commit the modified autoloader to the projects repository, so every time I run update, I can just check it back out. This will also help identify if any changes where made into the autoloader core.

Answer (score 1):

A safer alternative that works regardless of how the file is loaded (autoload, explicit require or include) is to simply call the static initializer after the class definition:

```
class Foo {
    private static $__constructed = false;

    public static function __static() {
        if (self::$__constructed) return;

        // do initialization
        self::$__constructed = true;
    }
}

Foo::__static();
```

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing is:

- Modify the `vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php`
- Commit the modified class loaded to the project (but ignore the rest of the vendor directory)
- `git checkout vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php` after `composer update`